# Unable to ask a question due to tag selector not working

Tags: bug, status-completed

Although it seems to be working now (for me), I want to bring this up in the event that is stops again and I cannot do anything about it.

I found for a period of about 20 minutes (could have been longer but I hadn't tried posting before that) I was unable to add a new question to either the main SO site or Meta. The issue was that it wouldn't allow me to add any tags, I would just type but no auto-complete would appear which means no tags could be correctly added. This then causes a validation issue when trying to submit the question as SO requires at least one tag to be selected.

If this is a know issue, and had been fully resolved, then a simple acknowledgement from an appropriate member will suffice as solving this query for me, but I just wanted to add this in the event that other users are experiencing the issue and feeling helpless (as I was) with what to do about it.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254515/can-not-edit-select-tags-from-web-interfacecan-not-ask-questions

Comment: @Oded: Ok.. do we close as dupes if it's not on the same site? I guess SE Meta is an exception as it's not a completely different site. Or is that link just for reference?

Comment: No real way to close as dupe. Can just leave that here.